# How to get Bluetooth Headset battery status in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there any way to get the battery percentage of the bluetooth headset in android ?

help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should post what you've done so far, what you have Googled and so on. Simply asking people to Google for you is not very nice SO etiquette.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a standardized way of doing this or if it's possible at all. Have you Googled a bit and if so what did you find? I'm gonna offer a few links myself as they might lead to something:

- First of all I'd look into the [android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html) class. It will list connected headsets as generic [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)s. From there it seems like you can issue **vendor specific** commands to get different kinds of sensor information (like battery level).
- Check [this blog post](http://developer.plantronics.com/blogs/Cary/2012/11/26/plugging-into-plantronics-headset-sensor-events-via-android) from a Plantronics employee regarding Plantronics headset sensor access from Android. There's even an example app with source code.
- Check the [Sony Add-On SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/) for interfacing with certain kind of headsets using their SmartApp system