# How to get Bluetooth Headset battery level?

Tags: android, bluetooth, battery, batterylevel

I'm trying to build an app which gets battery level of currently connected Bluetooth headset. This app can be used on phones which don't have this functionality built-in.
While searching on stackoverflow, I found [How to get Bluetooth Headset battery status in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602224/how-to-get-bluetooth-headset-battery-status-in-android) this question. I got the currently connected Bluetooth headset using `BluetoothProfile.HEADSET` profile.
But in the device object of type `BluetoothDevice` I don't see any method or property to get battery level of Bluetooth Headset.
I can get the device name and `isAudioConnected`.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539535/how-to-get-the-battery-level-after-connect-to-the-ble-device

Comment: You need the headset to provide that information.

Comment: How do I check whether the headset is providing that information or not? On play store there are apps which provide battery level. How do they work?

Comment: @Sahil Try batON https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.limi.baton&hl=en_IN

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, but it only works on android 8 and above

I took this code from [here](https://github.com/pefdneves/MyDots)

## Kotlin

```
 fun getBatteryLevel(pairedDevice: BluetoothDevice?): Int {
    return pairedDevice?.let { bluetoothDevice ->
        (bluetoothDevice.javaClass.getMethod("getBatteryLevel"))
            .invoke(pairedDevice) as Int
    } ?: -1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If question is about Bluetooth HFP feature: HF indicators feature is optional for the both sides. If the both sides support it, `BluetoothHeadset` will broadcast `BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_HF_INDICATORS_VALUE_CHANGED` with `BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_HF_INDICATORS_IND_ID` equal 2 (Battery Level) and `BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_HF_INDICATORS_IND_VALUE` with scope 0..100. Do not remember Android version were it was implemented, you should check it.

Also battery level can be implemented in device using vendor specific HFP AT commands (especially for old handsfree devices) and maybe BLE.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to register BroadcastReciver by      "android.bluetooth.device.action.BATTERY_LEVEL_CHANGED"

and you can receive this action by the broadcast receiver then get extra data by "android.bluetooth.device.extra.BATTERY_LEVEL"

and if you want to trigger this action, you need to reconnect your Bluetooth device or Bluetooth device battery level happened to change.

Good luck for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am Able to achieve the handset battery Level in Java

```
   try {                      
          BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("Connected device ID");
          java.lang.reflect.Method method;
          method = device.getClass().getMethod("getBatteryLevel");
          int value = (int) method.invoke(device);
          result.success(value);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
          result.error("invalid_argument", "'deviceId' argument is required to be string", null);
          break;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **@Kirill Martyuk** answer as an Extension variable

```
val BluetoothDevice.batteryLevel
    get() = this.let { device ->
        val method = device.javaClass.getMethod("getBatteryLevel")
        method.invoke(device) as Int?
      } ?: -1
```

Usage would be something like

```
val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager?
val adapter = manager?.adapter
val devices = adapter?.bondedDevices.orEmpty()
devices.forEach { device ->
    Log.d("DEVICE_NAME", device.name)
    Log.d("CHARGE_LEVEL", device.batteryLevel.toString())
}
```