# How to get battery percentage or low battery information(to be specific) of the RCU in Android TV

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-tv, bluetooth-gatt

How to get the information about current battery level or low battery level information of the RCU (remote control unit) for my Android TV.

I need to show customised message when the battery level is low i.e., "Time to change the battery....." or similar.

I've seen that the system detects the low battery and shows a system notification, but not sure how can i my application (which is a system application) can get that information.

I've already tried the below approaches, doesn't seems to work

[How to get the battery level after connect to the BLE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539535/how-to-get-the-battery-level-after-connect-to-the-ble-device)

[How to get Bluetooth Headset battery level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002816/how-to-get-bluetooth-headset-battery-level)

and this as well

```
    val btManager = getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    val mBluetoothAdapter = btManager.adapter
    val pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices

    val build = StringBuilder()
    for (bt in pairedDevices){
            val method: Method = bt.javaClass.getMethod("getBatteryLevel")
            val value = method.invoke(bt) as Int
            build.append(" (Battery : $value)")
    }
    val tvDetails = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_details);
    tvDetails.text = build.toString()
```

None of the above method has worked so far, Also i couldn't find anything specific in Official documentation.

Please let me know if anyone know or have found the solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "None of the above method has worked so far"? Did you get any error messages? Does your remote offer information about the battery level through BLE? Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to scan for your remote and see what kind of services it offers

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp) isn't available on google play for my device.
Also to answer your question, when i try to connectGatt for the RCU, it doesn't throws any error but, the list of services is empty.

Comment: Please try another BLE scanner, one that comes to mind would be LightBlue

Comment: I checked there's no BLE scanner available for ATV

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your first comment. Please install the app on your phone